# Merge events to perform async work with RxJs and Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

So I have a checkbox that is tied to a model:

```
<mat-checkbox  [(ngModel)]="element[column]" (click)="updateRow(element, $event)"></mat-checkbox>
```

The click event is supposed to call the server and perform a write in the db.

So, for this, I thought that using `concatMap`  was enough since it waits before making the next call to avoid exhausting the database.

```
updateRow(row, $event): void {
    Observable.from([{ row: row }])
      .concatMap(i => this._definitionService.updateDefinition(i)  //async work
      .subscribe(result => console.log('row updated'), error => {
        this.snack(error);
      });
  }
```

The problem is that it does not wait since every event change is a new call, and performing too many changes exhaust the database.

What would be the solution for this? I thought about tying the events using `fromEvent` like this:

```
Observable.fromEvent($event.target, 'click')
              .subscribe(i => {
                console.log(i);
              });
```

But, it only works when clicking `twice` on the checkbox.

What would be the correct approach?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to perform all the calls or can you apply a debouncer?

Comment: I need to perform all the calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it's calling many requests is because every time you click the element you call `updateRow` that creates new instance of `Observable.from`. So `concatMap` won't help you because you when you make 10 clicks it subscribes to 10 different Observables with 10 different `concatMap`s.

Probably the easiest way to achieve what you want is creating an intermediate Subject and pushing item into it every time you call `updateRow`:

```
const s = new Subject();

s.concatMap(i => this._definitionService.updateDefinition(i))
  .subscribe(
    result => console.log('row updated'),
    error => this.snack(error),
  );

...

updateRow(row, $event): void {
  s.next({ row });
}
```

Now you'll have just one subscription and pushing multiple item into Subject `s` (with `next()`) will execute them in order one after another.